# HTML Form Check required="" Before onclick="window.print()"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple web form that, once the submit button has been pressed, checks to see if all required fields have data and then prints.

Here's an example of what I have so far.

```
<form>
    <span><input value="" required=""/><label>First</label></span>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="window.print()"/>
</form>
```

When a user clicks the submit button, the page is sent to the printer. Then once the page has been printed and the user returns to the page, THEN the required check is made by the browser. How can I flip these functions?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Do you use jQuery in your project? Or are you looking for pure-JS solution to this problem?

Comment: Why no just write a function and call it?

Comment: @jevgenig My site does use jQuery.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove your `onclick` and instead use `onsubmit` on the form.

```
<form  onsubmit="window.print();">
    <span><input value="" required=""/><label>First</label></span>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: You are a boss ;)